# How to set expiry while put() using cache2k

Tags: cache2k

I want something like redis set and ttl, such as

public void put(K key, V value, int timeToLive, TimeUnit timeUnit);
public long ttl(K key);

and one more operation that redis doesn't provide

public void putWithIdle(K key, V value, int timeToIdle, TimeUnit timeUnit);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct API for this, but after `put`ing the value, you can change the expiry time as described here https://cache2k.org/docs/1.0/user-guide.html#entry-processor

`cache.invoke("key",
       e -> e.setValue("value").setExpiry(System.currentTimeMillis() + 
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(120)));`

Consider creating a feature request at https://github.com/cache2k/cache2k/issues